# Hot Load Error- Failed to receive keepalive

Tags: meteor

I've upgraded to 0.9.0.1 and that appeared to be smooth, an my meteor site works well.

However, on making a simple change to a template - literally changing a text inside a span - I get an error in the server console and the server then restarts.

server console log:

```
=> App running at: http://localhost:3000/
=> Client modified -- refreshing 
I20140828-10:21:38.261(1)? Failed to receive keepalive! Exiting.
=> Exited with code: 1
=> Meteor server restarted
```

This appears to be related to new hotload process

> When running your app with the local development server, changes that
>   only affect the client no longer require restarting the server.
>   Changes that only affect CSS no longer require the browser to refresh
>   the page, both in local development and in some production
>   environments. #490

What could cause this  `Failed to receive keepalive!` error?

Comment: I have the same issue here. My colleagues working on the same repo don't have the issue so it's not a package issue.

Comment: See discussion here: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/2536

Comment: It's been reportedly fixed and will be released soon.

Answer (score 0):

It seems from looking around the internet and on the IRC channel this could have one or two causes:

- use of an incompatible package that got past the 0.9.x tests
- some bad coding such a missed placed comma which when meteor compiles the application is forcing an error.

Or of course it could be both. Or something entirely different.

For me it was an incompatible package.

Comment: CPU usage is normal I my case. Must be something else.